# invert colors in image

Tags: matlab

Can i invert each color and generate a inverted RGB image by matlab code? and how?
i want to invert each color then calculate the sum which is the new value for the pixel
somehow like this ((255-R)+(255-B)+(255-G))
thnx

Answer (score 4):

```
myimage = sum(255 - myimage, 3);
```

Explanation:

- `255 - myimage` does the *pixel-wise* color inversion, *e.g.* for each pixel, the R component becomes (255-R) and so on…
- `sum(…, 3)` does the *pixel-wise* sum of each of the 3 layers of the image (Red, Green and Blue)

You end up with a single layer image where each pixel stores the corresponding sum that you are looking for.

Comment: this is invert the whole image, i need to invert each pixel in the image. thank u

Comment: What is the difference? If each pixel gets inverted, then the whole image is inverted!

Comment: i want to invert each color then calculate the sum then invert the sum.

Comment: Then edit your question and make it clear. I don't understand exactly what you are asking.

Comment: somehow like this
((255-R)+(255-B)+(255-G))

Comment: Sigh. That is EXACTLY what sum(255 - RGB,3) does. EXACTLY.